# PrimeFaces 5.0 javascript error - b.debug("PrimeFaces already load

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, liferay-6

I have got the follow error.

Here the source js code:

```
(function(a){if(a.PrimeFaces){b.debug("PrimeFaces already loaded, ignoring duplicate execution.");return}var b={escapeClientId:function(c){return"#"+c.replace(/:/g,"\\:")}...
```

And the error is:
**undefined is null or not is an object**

The error refers to debug function of "b" variable.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which PrimeFaces version?

Comment: You are probably running into a Liferay Faces issue: [FACES-1977](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1977) or (maybe) [FACES-2007](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-2007). Try the patch for [FACES-1977](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1977) and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem with PrimeFaces 5.1, JSF 2.1.Looking in html code I didn't find double primefaces.js inclusion

Answer (score 0):

this is a primefaces problem, I've submitted a pull request: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/143

Till it's fixed you can patch your primefaces.js in following way:

```
function(a){if(a.PrimeFaces){a.PrimeFaces.debug("PrimeFaces already loaded, ignoring duplicate execution.");return}
```